# Could someone help me understand this sentence

Tags: translation, usage

Can anyone help me understand this sentence?  太郎は春子にたばこを吸われた。 I’m having a really hard time understanding the translation given: “taro had a cigarette smoked by Haruko on him.” Is there another way to translate it into English that makes a bit more sense? I’ve tried searching for the sentence online to hopefully find someone who had the same question, but I couldn’t find anything.

Comment: Try searching for the phrase "suffering passive"

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15933/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/28263/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/4947/9831