# Is 悪いところを見つかった proper Japanese?

Tags: grammar, expressions

The [weblio page](https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8B%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F) for 見つかった uses this phrase as an example meaning "I've been caught." But as I understand it, 見つかる implies that the subject and not the object is the thing that is found. And so I would expect it to be

悪いところが見つかった。

or otherwise

悪いところを見つけた。

This example seems to be the only one on the weblio page to use を with 見つかった.

Comment: not sure if you already know it or not, but 見つかる is an intransitive verb, and 見つける a transitive one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

***Different Meanings of 「ところ」***

> 「悪{わる}いところ**を**見つかった。」

is at least colloquially a valid phrase meaning:

> "(Someone) was caught at an awkward moment."

In this expression, 「ところ」 means a "scene" or "moment" where an action takes place.

「～～**を**見つかる」 is not a structure you would use in formal speech, but that can be said about a million other words and phrases.

The sentence:

> 「悪いところ**が**見つかった。」

however, means a ***completely*** different thing.  It means:

> "A bad / malfunctioning part was found."

「ところ」 means a "part" in this sentence.  It may refer to a part of one's body or an object such as a car, TV, PC, etc..  This sentence implies that an ***examination has been conducted*** that lead to the finding of the malfunctioning part.

Comment: How common is it in colloquial Japanese to use を to mark something other than the direct object? Do you know of any other expressions where を is used in this way? Also, is there a "correct" way to express the same idea in formal Japanese?

Comment: @kohaku Here you are... https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18715/7810 (ProTip: in formal Japanese you still use を)